# vb.net database query and checkbox , proper way to do?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Vb.net and Sql Server(don't be harsh). Can anybody check my code, i feel it is wrong way to do. The purpose is to show query only if check-box is clicked and shows that query.
Thank you very much.

```
 Private Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click

    CheckValue = 0 'set to value 0 
    'check if any checkbox is checked.
    For Each C As Control In Me.Controls
        If C.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
            Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(C, CheckBox)
            If cb.Checked Then
                CheckValue = CheckValue + 1 'only works if value is above 1
            End If
        End If
    Next


    If CheckValue <> 0 Then   'only if check box is checked then rest will run

        Try
            If chkboxId.Checked = True Then 'assign value to checkbox
                chkboxIdstr = "userid"
            Else
                chkboxIdstr = ""
            End If

            If chkboxName.Checked = True Then
                chkboxNamestr = "username"
            Else
                chkboxNamestr = ""
            End If

            'to insert comma, only if both are true.
            If chkboxId.Checked = True And chkboxName.Checked = True Then
                SQLcomma = " , "
            Else
                SQLcomma = ""
            End If

            'so if both are checked we get a comma
            SQL2 = chkboxIdstr + " " + SQLcomma + " " + chkboxNamestr
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Try 'sql connect and display
            sqlCon.Open()
            SQL = "SELECT " + SQL2 + " FROM user_info"

            Dim dadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, sqlCon)
            Dim dset As New DataSet
            sqlCon.Close()
            dadapter.Fill(dset)
            'fill datagrid
            dgv.DataSource = dset.Tables(0)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            sqlCon.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Plesase do check any box to filter ")
        Exit Sub

    End If
End Sub
```

--
I learn by doing small application(trail and error), mostly google search for solutions.

Comment: You dont need to open the connection if u are using SqlDataAdapter, because it does it byitself

Comment: Just a question. What would you do if you have to pass an value to your Select statement? Lets say you have to select a row where the userid is 45. How would you pass the 45?

Comment: Manuchao. I have no idea. I will check it.

Comment: Well I will tell you just for the case, because you cant avoid it :).    "SELECT userid FROM user_info where userid = @value"    user_info"dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",45)

Comment: Thank you Manuchao. But i will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need all that code. Just test your checkbox one by one and build incrementally the list of columns to add to the SELECT query....

```
Dim selectColumns As String
Try

    If chkboxId.Checked = True Then 
        selectColumns = "userid,"
    End If

    If chkboxName.Checked = True Then
        selectColumns &= "username,"
    End If

    ' Other columns???? follow the same pattern

    ' If we have something in selectColumns then we could execute the query
    ' but before we trim away the last comma
    If selectColumns.Length > 0 Then 
       selectColumns = selectColumn.TrimEnd(",")

       sqlCon.Open()
       SQL = "SELECT " & selectColumns & " FROM user_info"
       .....
    Else
       ' no data in selectColumns? Message for you user
       MsgBox("Plesase do check any box to filter ")
       Exit Sub
    End If    
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    sqlCon.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Had an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". after giving value for selectColumns its ok .

Comment: Steve, Thank you so much. Learning programming in my spare time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click

    If chkboxId.Checked OrElse chkboxName.Checked Then
        SQL2 = String.Empty
        If chkboxId.Checked Then
            SQL2 = SQL2 + "userid"
        EndIf

        If chkboxId.Checked AndAlso chkboxName.Checked Then
            SQL2 = SQL2 + " , "
        End If

        If chkboxName.Checked Then
            SQL2 = SQL2 + "username"
        End If

        Try 'sql connect and display
            sqlCon.Open()
            SQL = "SELECT " + SQL2 + " FROM user_info"

            Dim dset As New DataSet
            Using dadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, sqlCon)
                dadapter.Fill(dset)
            End Using

            'fill datagrid
            dgv.DataSource = dset.Tables(0)

          Catch ex As Exception
             MsgBox(ex.Message)
          Finally
             sqlCon.Close()
          End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Please do check any box to filter ")
    End If

End Sub
```